# How to make pydev/eclipse compile cython modules on a Windows platform

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, cython

My IDE is pydev/eclipse on Win XP.

I like the idea of compiling cython modules inside the IDE, but I 
can only get it to work on a Linux box.

> right-click on the project-->properties-->builders-->new-->program

I have tried with the simplest setup.py and helloworld.pyx as posted here:

http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html

This is my screen on Linux

[image: pydev/eclipse builder settings]

It compiles the helloworld.pyx in the usual way, as

> python setup.py build_ext --inplace

However, on WinXP, with the same settings, again after clicking

> project-->build project

I get

[image]

I.e. "is not a valid Win32 application".

Any clue why this does not work on WinXP?

Update: **Problem solved by Fabio**. This works:

[image: adjust_location_and_wd]

Comment: With the PyDev perspective open, go to Window/preferences.  On the left panel select Pydev, then 'Interpreter - Python'.  Check that it is pointing at a valid Python installation.

Comment: Thanks, checked it. It does point at my standard Python install (...\Python27\python.exe) and "python setup.py build_ext --inplace" does work from a Windows cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because it's trying to execute setup.py as if it was an executable...

The problem in your specific use-case is that external builders know nothing about python, so, the location should actually map to your python.exe (and the setup.py location should be passed as a parameter).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, I posted your solution above. Still curious why this is different for Windows.

Comment: I believe it's different because on linux, if the setup.py has the shebang (i.e.: #!/usr/bin/python) in the start of the file it can interpret it with a shell (but not on windows) -- note that you should mark the solution as accepted if it worked for you.